# Cannot install programs on shared screen using Zoom

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, sql-server, zoom-meeting

I am trying to install SQL Server and Visual Studio on my friend's system using a shared screen using the application **Zoom**. I have downloaded the files in the said computer using screen sharing but I cannot install it.

When I click the downloaded files nothing happens. It won't open. I have complete permission to operate the PC, but still nothing works.

I tried to troubleshoot it by searching on Google, but I can't seem to find anything that helps me resolve this.

Comment: Does the UAC prompt pop up, maybe? Zoom probably wouldn't be able to display and interact with those, you need someone at the PC to confirm them.

Comment: I dont kno bro!! let me check! Thank You....  @gronostaj

Comment: Most screen share utilities, to avoid being used by scammers to install malware, do not support remote control of a UAC prompt. Not even Skype. Only dedicated remote support tools offer this function, to my knowledge.